# form failing to submit html elements in contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, html

on submit of the form which contains a contenteditable div, the value sent as POST data is only text excluding any html elements in it. for example an image

```
$("div.input").append("<img src='"+img+"' />"); // append image
 var txt=$('.'+tto).html(); //get the contenteditablediv content
 $('#send_data').append('<input type="hidden" value="'+txt+'" id="valueToSend" name="txt">'); 
 // submit form
 $('#send_data').ajaxForm({
           success: function(dd){
               alert(dd);
           }
        }).submit();
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how do i get to submit both text and html elements there in

Answer (score 0):

`$("div").text()` can be used to get only text from `div` tags excluding `html` elements.

Comment: i used .html() which gets both of them but the html fails to accompany the text when the form is submitted